# What is the probability $P(Z<X+Y)$ given a function of $3$ variables?

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus

What is the probability $P(Z<X+Y)$ given $f(x,y,z)=24xy^2z^3$ for $x,y,z\in(0,1)$?

I can't find the bounds of the triple integral. I keep getting the answer of $1/18$ whereas the book says it's $1/14$. My bounds for the innermost variable ($z$) are $0$ to $x+y$, for $y$: $0$ to $1-x$, and for $x$: $0$ to $1$.

I can't see how to find the region that describes $Z<X+Y$. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

When you say $0\leq y\leq 1-x$, you're making the condition that $X+Y\leq1$, but that's not required.  For example, we could have $X=Y=\frac34$ and and value $0\leq Z\leq1$ would work.  In short, in addition to the integral you computed, you need $$\int_0^1\int_{1-x}^1\int_0^1f(x,y,z)dzdydx$$

Comment: Yes, I see that now. So the additional integral works out to 0.9. That makes the total 0.9+ 1/18 = 43/45. Is that the correct probability? The answer he gives in the book is 1/14. Is he wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: That's the same answer I get, so I would say the answer in the book is wrong, unless I'm making a mistake.  One way to check: another formula for the probability is $$1-\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}\int_{x+y}^1f(x,y,z)dzdydx$$